# CCClippingnode causes OpenGL error 0x0502

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es, ccsprite

I'm using cocos2d-iPhone v.2.2, updating an old game, and I have a clipping node that is causing an error. In AppDelegate.m, I switched the settings to use CCClippingNode:

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                               depthFormat:GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES //switched from 0
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];
```

And then I used this code to make the clipper in my mainGame.m

```
//after interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCClippingNode *shadowClipper;

//in the init method
CCSprite *stencil = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"clipper.png"];
stencil.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
_shadowClipper = [CCClippingNode clippingNodeWithStencil:stencil];
_shadowClipper.alphaThreshold = 0.0;
[_gameLayer addChild:_shadowClipper z:2];
```

The console logs "OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[CCSprite draw] 530" but other than that the clipping node is doing what it's supposed to in the simulator. Any ideas about what's causing the error and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: If you leave the alphaThreshold alone (defaults to 1), the error should disappear (although you - like me - may not want to leave the threshold at 1). CCClippingNode applies a different shader to all nodes used as stencil. This seems to be related to the problem, but I haven't found out why exactly the error occurs yet.

Comment: Have you tried to analyze an OpenGL frame in the debug navigator in Xcode? It may provide more detailed error messages. You can also go to CCSprite, line 530 and add a couple of CHECK_GL_ERRORs to find out which line causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using two nested `CCClippingNodes`, both of which have `alphaThreshold` set to < 1. The observed error occurs once per frame. It is reported (!) in line 530 of `CCSprite` but occurs in `CCClippingNode` in line 285:

```
[program setUniformLocation:alphaValueLocation withF1:_alphaThreshold];
```

If the `alphaThreshold` is less than 1, `CCClippingNode` assigns an alpha test shader to all of its stencil nodes. When it updates the alpha threshold uniform in the above line, it does so without calling `glUseProgram` before, so the implementation attempts to set a uniform which may not be present in the currently bound shader.

Add the following line before the above line in `CCClippingNode` to bind the shader program before its uniform is set. This should get rid of the error.

```
[program use];
```

`CCClippingNode` appears to be a little rough around the edges, at least the alpha test implementation...

Comment: Without the alpha threshold at 0, `CCClippingNode` was clipping at the bounding box of the sprite instead of where it had alpha. Luckily, your solution worked perfectly. Thanks!